# Docker images jenkins server - Efficient space usage

Tags: docker, jenkins, microservices

I'm currently using jenkins in CI to

1) Check out code from github
2) Perform static analysis
3) build jar files
4) Create docker file and create docker image
5) Push docker file to private docker registry

I have three microservices and What I have found out is that for each jenkins job run, it creates the image on the jenkins server which costs 1.8 GB.

sudo docker images

```
dockerrepo:5000/reward     1                   94791f0ea2f7        13 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/reward     latest              94791f0ea2f7        13 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/mission    1                   3f5f81975f60        13 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/mission    latest              3f5f81975f60        13 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/employee   1                   51ba73ad9f48        13 hours ago        695.4 MB
dockerrepo:5000/employee   latest              51ba73ad9f48        13 hours ago        695.4 MB
dockerrepo:5000/reward     <none>              81a9d4287823        19 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/mission    <none>              8bde5a7db299        19 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/employee   <none>              0468a6fdb274        19 hours ago        695.4 MB
dockerrepo:5000/reward     <none>              90aafe222219        20 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/mission    <none>              993fbe1add06        20 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/employee   <none>              ed3e79c4358d        20 hours ago        695.4 MB
dockerrepo:5000/reward     <none>              55ee8ff2e862        21 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/mission    <none>              cd916601c5ae        21 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/employee   <none>              c161547cb40f        21 hours ago        695.4 MB
dockerrepo:5000/reward     <none>              0ab760a9c1da        24 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/mission    <none>              379f403173ec        24 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/employee   <none>              59611b29e023        24 hours ago        695.4 MB
dockerrepo:5000/reward     <none>              d4782e03237c        25 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/mission    <none>              3da34e04c5fa        25 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/employee   <none>              683104822e13        25 hours ago        695.4 MB
dockerrepo:5000/reward     <none>              a9c10a0b4376        42 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/mission    <none>              5818f60cc0db        42 hours ago        682 MB
dockerrepo:5000/employee   <none>              e819c78da2fc        42 hours ago        695.4 MB
```

Docker file used for a single microservice

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD Mission/target/Mission.jar missionfinal.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /missionfinal.jar'
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongodb/microservices", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/missionfinal.jar"]
```

Now I have 16 GB of images and it is going to grow, this is just a POC and I cant imagine how they do for hundreds of microservices.

Is the simple solution to delete it from the jenkins server as soon as it is pushed to repository? Any other tips and suggestions to improve the process please.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you remove the unused images? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/

Comment: I could do that, just wanted to confirm if it won't affect anything and also a clean way of doing it since it is automation and I don't want stuff dangling.  So I guess I could run the prune command on the jenkins server after the automation is complete?